# function attribute lifespan

Tags: python, memoization, function-attributes

I'm writing a memoization of a function and I want to store an attribute in the function object.
Will the function attribute be available for the lifespan of the process? if not how can I achieve such a thing?

Thank you

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Everything you store in global objects and variables in the program persists for the lifetime of the program. Why would function attributes be any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret this question as "can I reasonably expect a user-defined attribute of a function object to persist through the entire lifetime of my program? For example, in this code:

```
def f():
    f.x += 1
    return f.x

f.x = 0

print(f())
print(f())
print(f())

#desired result:
#1
#2
#3
```

... Is it guaranteed that f.x won't spontaneously lose its value halfway through?"

The `x` attribute of the function `f` will retain its value for the entire lifetime of `f`. Functions defined at the global scope live for the entire lifetime of the program. So you can safely use `f.x` for memoization.